# Normality test for C#?

Tags: c#, statistics, normal-distribution

We've got a PRNG in our code base, which we think has a bug in it's method to produce numbers which conform to a given normal distribution.

Is there a C# implementation of a normality test which I can leverage in my unit test suite to assert that this module behaves as desired/expected?

My preference would be something that has a signature like:

```
bool NormalityTest.IsNormal(IEnumerable<int> samples)
```

Comment: Is normality all that is important, or is randomness also important?

Comment: Good Q.... if you have some randomness tests in C# (DIEHARD etc), that'd be helpful, too... but this question is aimed at "is this set of sample values look normal" question.

Answer (score 1):

Math.Net has distribution functions and random number sampling. It is probably the most widely used math library, very solid.

http://numerics.mathdotnet.com/

http://mathnetnumerics.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Probability%20Distributions&referringTitle=Documentation

Comment: Which functions from this package do you recommend? From http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normality_test, I was trying to find something like Lilliefors test.

Comment: Does your PRNG inherit from the .net `Random` class?

Comment: No... why would that matter?

Comment: Because many of the classes in the `MathNet.Numerics.Distributions` namespace of this library require the random number generator to do this. Also its best practice in .Net custom RNG.

Comment: We tried implementing Kolmogorov-Smirnov using this library, but it ended up rejecting normal distributions which we accepted via historgram inspection... how exactly were you suggesting this library would be useful to answer the question?

Answer (score 1):

You can try this: http://accord-framework.net/docs/html/T_Accord_Statistics_Testing_ShapiroWilkTest.htm

Scroll down to the example:

```
// Let's say we would like to determine whether a set
// of observations come from a normal distribution:
double[] samples =
{
    0.11, 7.87, 4.61, 10.14, 7.95, 3.14, 0.46, 4.43,
    0.21, 4.75, 0.71, 1.52, 3.24, 0.93, 0.42, 4.97,
    9.53, 4.55, 0.47, 6.66
};

// For this, we can use the Shapiro-Wilk test. This test tests the null hypothesis 
// that samples come from a Normal distribution, vs. the alternative hypothesis that 
// the samples do not come from such distribution. In other words, should this test
// come out significant, it means our samples do not come from a Normal distribution.

// Create a new Shapiro-Wilk test:
var sw = new ShapiroWilkTest(samples);

double W = sw.Statistic; // should be 0.90050
double p = sw.PValue;    // should be 0.04209
bool significant = sw.Significant; // should be true

// The test is significant, therefore we should reject the null 
// hypothesis that the samples come from a Normal distribution.
```

Answer (score 0):

I do not know of any [c-implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18676763/shapiro-wilk-test-in-objective-c) of testing data for normality. I had the same issue and build my own routine. [This web-page](http://www.real-statistics.com/tests-normality-and-symmetry/statistical-tests-normality-symmetry/shapiro-wilk-expanded-test/) helped me a lot. It is written for executing the test in Excel but it gives you all the necessary coefficients (Royston) and the logic.

Comment: That's definitely the right idea.... wish I had access to it from my nunit tests.